# Save Table or li items in csv dynamically using python

Tags: python, csv

I have wrote a script that fetches the specifications of products. I am successfully able to get all specifications. But the whole reason for getting the specs dynamically was that some products have 5 specs, some have 20+. Now problem is when I reach the step of saving data in csv the same problem appears again, which is if number of specs are different for every other product how row_info can be dynamic?

Currently i wrote this script for a product with 5 spec items as in previous question But it won't work for any other product with more than 5 specs:

```
mainPage = requests.get("http://umall.pk/rivo-rhythm-rx40.html")
mainTree = html.fromstring(mainPage.text)
header = {'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
i = 0

with open('umallPK-'+ '(rivo)' +'-products.csv', 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for title in mainTree.xpath('(//*[@id="product_addtocart_form"]/div[@class="product-name"]/text())[2]'):
        title = title.strip()
        print (title)

    specs = []
    specNames = []
    row_dynamic = []

    while (mainTree.xpath("//tr[" + str(i+1) + "]")):
        specNames.append([specName for specName in mainTree.xpath("//tr[" + str(i+1) + "]/td[1]/text()")])

        specs.append([spec for spec in mainTree.xpath("//tr[" + str(i+1) + "]/td[2]/text()")])

        ##This was just an experiment I was doing.
        row_dynamic.append("specNames[" + str(i) + "]")

        i += 1

    print (row_dynamic)

    row_info = ["Title", specNames[0], specNames[1], specNames[2], specNames[3], specNames[4]]

    row_info2 = [title, specs[0], specs[1], specs[2], specs[3], specs[4]]

    csvwriter.writerow(row_info)
    csvwriter.writerow(row_info2)
```

Comment: I can take a stab at your code, but there can be a couple of ways to do this based on the structure of the page you're scraping. Can you share the link as well?

Comment: @TheLaughingMan Added the complete code with a product having 21 specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating your approach a little. You don't have to be so inflexible in dealing with tables when scraping. It's problematic when you don't fall back to basic Python when manipulating simple elements because you want to keep a library-based approach (no offense to `lxml` users, but not all manipulation should be done on the `xpath` level).

Since the tables are simple 2-column variants, even if they vary in length, the number of `td` tags will always be even, even if the right hand side is empty. This means that we can just get all the `td` elements in one go and do some basic Python manipulation to get what we want.

```
import requests as rq
from lxml import html

mainPage = rq.get("http://umall.pk/rivo-rhythm-rx40.html")
mainTree = html.fromstring(mainPage.text)

paths_dict = {
    'title': '(//*[@id="product_addtocart_form"]/div[@class="product-name"]/text())[2]',
    'table': '//*[@id="product-attribute-specs-table"]/tr/td/text()'
}

title = mainTree.xpath(paths_dict['title'])[0].strip()
print title

table = mainTree.xpath(paths_dict['table'])
header = table[::2]
values = table[1::2]

print header
print values
```

The above code returns the following result:

```
RIVO RHYTHM RX40
['Weight ', 'Tag line', 'Model', 'Type', 'Processor', 'Network', 'Connectivity', 'Memory', 'RAM', 'Sim Type', 'Display Type', 'Screen Size', 'Screen Resolution', 'OS', 'Camera', 'Features', 'SIM Modules', 'Battery', 'Warranty', 'Brand', 'Refund Policy']
['0.3430', 'Take Control', 'Rhythm RX40', 'Smart Phone', 'Dual Core', 'N/A', 'N/A', '4GB', '512 mb', 'N/A', 'IPS Display', '4. inches ', 'IPS High Resolution', 'KitKat ', '5 MP', 'IPS Capacitive Touch Screen Display', 'Dual SIM', '1750 mAh', '12', 'Rivo', 'N/A']
```

No matter the length of the table or number of specs, this will always get the correct headers and correct row values in their respective positions **iff** the table is not following an esoteric structure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it helped but about my problem when saving it in csv will still not produce my required output. as you can see i want to add title in header as well so i can save product name in proper format as well and thanks for your effort. You gave me a new way to manipulate data,

Comment: I need to save every spec in different cell, like weight in A1, Tag Line in B1, Model in C1 and so on. thats why i used "["Title", specNames[0], specNames[1], specNames[2], specNames[3], specNames[4]]". By following your method I get header values in A1 only which I already got with " row_info = ["Title", specNames]".